# edit / customize RStudio Editor themes (.rsTheme to .tmTheme)

Tags: r, themes, rstudio

There's a huge repository of RStudio Editor themes and the option to customize them here:
[TmThemeEditor](https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Monokai). You can also upload your own .tmTheme for further editing.

However, how to edit RStudio Editor themes that are stored as a .rsTheme file? I would need to back transform it somehow to a .tmTheme file to edit it online.

To use a .tmTheme in RStudio, u just need to import it into RStudio and RStudio converts it into a .rsTheme. Any idea how to edit .rsTheme directly or transform it back to .tmTheme?

I would like to avoid editing the file manually in Notepad++ etc. and find the .ace entry that matches the one I want to change (see [tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudio-extensions/rstudio-theme-creation.html)).